# Strange behavior of Windows Server 2003 task scheduler

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows, scheduled-task, task-scheduler

I've got a task, which runs fine while launching it with "Right click / Run" in the scheduler, but fails with a weird "SQL Server login fail" due to bad login while ran automatically at specified time.

Login for SQL Server is internal SQL Server account, not a "Trusted connection" Windows account. I know the login (and all others parameters) are good.
Also, I've got some other tasks launched on the same server which runs fine. This one is the only exception. Nothing in the task requires an opened session.

Like I said previously I can't figure why it's ok to launch it by the "Run" command in scheduler but not at specified time. And of course I'm sure my DB server is always available.

Does somebody know if there are significant differences between launching the task by "Right click / Run" and awaiting for it to be started automatically ?

As I don't have this behavior with other tasks I'm pretty sure it's a bug in scheduler but I can't even guess what happens here.

Comment: [Procmon.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)